# Is there any way to disallow a component from rendering using `ShouldRender`, yet allow its children to rerender as they see fit?

Tags: blazor

If a component has a child component that takes a reference type Foo as a parameter, then any HTML event completion will cause the child to rerender: in the below **Index.razor**, clicking the button will cause the BarPanel to re-render.

```cs
<BarPanel InputFoo="Foo1" />
<button @onclick="()=>{}" />
```

Now if BarPanel is onerous to render and/or present many times, I might choose to override its ShouldRender to reduce this re-render frequency.

But suppose further BarPanel has a child QuxPanel, and it also takes an InputFoo--in **BarPanel.razor**:

```cs
<span>@InputFoo.Bar</span> 
<QuxPanel InputFoo="InputFoo" />
@code { 
   [Parameter] Foo InputFoo {get;set;}
   protected override bool ShouldRender() {
      ...
   }
}
```

And of course in **QuxPanel.razor**:

```cs
<span>@InputFoo.Qux</span>
@code { 
   [Parameter] Foo InputFoo {get;set;}
}
```

So on a UI event completion in Index, I'd like to permit a re-render of QuxPanel nested inside BarPanel, but it seems that I can't unless BarPanel knows about it and re-renders first.  But BarPanel is the expensive component, and I'd like to rerender its children while preventing it from re-rendering (for example, when `Qux` changes but `Bar` remains unchanged).  **Is there any way to disallow a component from rendering using `ShouldRender`, yet allow its children to rerender as they see fit?**

Comment: Hi.  there are several answers to your question, but before putting pen to paper, I'd like to understand what you mean by onerous/expensive to render.   Lots of html to build out and display, lots of number crunching, lots of data access???

Comment: Mostly the former: "Lots of HTML" with not a lot of change.  One example is when I'm rendering rows of a table and each cell is rendered by a component.  When one cell out of a row changes,  It would be nice if the Row component could return ShouldRender false but still let one component in the row have ShouldRender true and let it alone re-render while the other few hundred cells and dozen rows on the screen don't re-render.

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't worry.  The Renderer diffing engine works out what has changed in the DOM and only dispatches the changes to the browser.  You should have a very good understanding of the whole rendering process before selectively rendering components.

However, if you want to go down that route, you need to drive rendering through events.  Here's some demo code that also monitors SetParameter and Render events in components.

#### BaseService

A very basic notification Service. Make sure you register it as a Scoped Service.

```
    public class BaseService
    {
        public void NotifyComponentANeedstoRender()
            => ReRenderComponentA?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        public event EventHandler ReRenderComponentA;
    }
```

#### BaseControl

```
@implements IDisposable
<div class="border-1 m-1 p-1">
    <div class="bg-dark text-light">
        <span>
            Sets: @_sets
        </span>
        <span>
            Renders: @_renders
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-1">
            @this.ChildContent
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    private int _renders = 1;
    private int _sets = 0;

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public bool ShouldNotRender { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public bool EventDriven { get; set; }

    [Inject] BaseService baseService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (EventDriven)
            baseService.ReRenderComponentA += OnRender;
    }

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        _sets++;
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (this.ShouldNotRender)
            return false;
        _renders++;
        return true;
    }

    private void OnRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (EventDriven)
            baseService.ReRenderComponentA -= OnRender;
    }

}
```

#### TestPage

Finally a demo razor page.

```
@page "/TestRender"
<BaseControl>
    <button class="btn btn-info me-2" @onclick="OnClickAsync">Increment Async</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">Increment</button>
    <BaseControl ShouldNotRender="true">
        <BaseControl>
            <BaseControl>
                Not the correct Clicks after intial render : @_clicks
            </BaseControl>
            <BaseControl EventDriven="true">
                <div>
                    The correct Clicks : @_clicks
                </div>
            </BaseControl>
        </BaseControl>
    </BaseControl>
    <BaseControl>
        <BaseControl>
            <BaseControl>
                The correct Clicks : @_clicks
            </BaseControl>
        </BaseControl>
    </BaseControl>
</BaseControl>

@code {

    [Inject] BaseService baseService { get; set; }

    private string _content => $"<div>{_clicks}</div>";

    private int _clicks;

    private async Task OnClickAsync()
    {
        _clicks++;
        this.baseService.NotifyComponentANeedstoRender();
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        _clicks++;
        this.baseService.NotifyComponentANeedstoRender();
    }
}
```

### Updates to the Answer

The only method the Renderer has to communicate with a Component is `SetParametersAsync`.  The Renderer has no method of directly running a re-render.  In `ComponentBase`, `SetParametersAsync` calls the `OnInitialized/OnParametersSet` method set and as part of that sequence calls `StateHasChanged` on one or more occasions.

When a render event occurs in a component, the Renderer needs to decide what's changed, and which child components need to know about the changes.  If it decides there's a change in one or more of a component's parameters, it calls `SetParametersAsync` on that component.  It's up to the component to decide if it needs to re-render.

Let's look at a couple of examples:

```
... component code
<BaseControl>
    Hello World
</BaseControl>
... component event handlers
```

At first glance you would think that `BaseControl` shouldn't update when a render event occurs in the parent - there's no parameters to change.  However, that isn't actually the case.  That "Hello World" gets compiled into a RenderFragment that gets passed to `BaseControl` as the `ChildContent` Parameter.  The RenderFragment is a delegate that the Renderer knows could have changed (it has no way of knowing if it has or hasn't), so it calls `SetParametersAsync` on `BaseControl`.

Example 2 looks like this:

```
... component code
<BaseControl/>
... component event handlers
```

Now `BaseControl` has no `ChildContent`, so the Renderer knows it's parameters haven't changed - `ChildContent` is still null - so it doesn't call `SetParamatersAsync`.

The same situation applies to objects and primitives.  The Renderer doesn't know if an object has changed - so it assumes it has - and calls   `SetParamatersAsync`.

Here's a couple of components and an updated test page to demo the differences.

##### PrimitiveControl

```
<div class="border-1 m-1 p-1">
    <div class="bg-dark text-light">
        <span>
            Sets: @_sets
        </span>
        <span>
            Renders: @_renders
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-1">
        <div>Value : @Value</div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Value { get; set; }

    private int _renders = 1;
    private int _sets = 0;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        _sets++;
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        _renders++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

##### ObjectControl

```
<div class="border-1 m-1 p-1">
    <div class="bg-dark text-light">
        <span>
            Sets: @_sets
        </span>
        <span>
            Renders: @_renders
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="p-1">
        @foreach (var str in Value)
        {
            <div>@str</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<string> Value { get; set; }

    private int _renders = 1;
    private int _sets = 0;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        _sets++;
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        _renders++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

##### Updated Test Page

```
@page "/TestRender"
<BaseControl>
    <button class="btn btn-info me-2" @onclick="OnClickAsync">Increment Async</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">Increment</button>
    <BaseControl ShouldNotRender="true">
        <BaseControl>
            <BaseControl>
                Not the correct Clicks after intial render : @_clicks
            </BaseControl>
            <BaseControl EventDriven="true">
                <div>
                    The correct Clicks : @_clicks
                </div>
            </BaseControl>
        </BaseControl>
    </BaseControl>
    <BaseControl>
        <BaseControl>
            <BaseControl>
                The correct Clicks : @_clicks
            </BaseControl>
        </BaseControl>
    </BaseControl>
</BaseControl>
<BaseControl>
    Hello World
</BaseControl>
<BaseControl/>
<ObjectControl Value="list" />
<PrimitiveControl Value="intvalue" />

@code {

    [Inject] BaseService baseService { get; set; }

    private string _content => $"<div>{_clicks}</div>";

    private int _clicks;

    private List<string> list = new List<string> { "Lagos", "Houston" };

    private int intvalue = 20;

    private async Task OnClickAsync()
    {
        _clicks++;
        this.baseService.NotifyComponentANeedstoRender();
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        _clicks++;
        this.baseService.NotifyComponentANeedstoRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote, "In general you shouldn't worry. The Renderer diffing engine works out what has changed in the DOM and only dispatches the changes to the browser."  This is not true in my example in the question: When the button is clicked, all components re-render even though nothing has changed. The system does not detect whether the properties inside BarPanel.Foo have not changed.  It only knows that they may have changed, so BarPanel will be rerendered.

Comment: A relevant clue seems to be here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0): "Components inherited from ComponentBase skip rerenders due to parameter updates if...All of the parameter values are of known immutable primitive types, such as int, string, DateTime, and haven't changed since the previous set of parameters were set."  My case is regarding a component with a parameter that is an ordinary (non-primitive) reference type.

Comment: Do I understand it right that your solution totally overrides the default rendering trigger for components that inject a BaseService?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski.  The Render Event doesn't mean the browser DOM gets rendered.  If I render a component in which there are no changes, nothing happens in the browser DOM.  The Blazor Renderer runs the queued RenderFragement, builds a Virtual DOM from the RenderTree, compares the new DOM with the old and sends the changes to the browser window.  IN WASM this happens in the Browser WebAssembly compartment, in Server in the SignalR session.

Comment: I agree, except I would not call that Virtual DOM process "rendering". When Microsoft uses the term "rendering" in Blazor, they seem to mean running all the component C# code as necessary to figure out what the new DOM should be and concludes by running OnAfterRender in the component. In my example above in the question, the render still executes but there is no DOM change. I agree that this avoids expensive DOM updates automatically, but in a real-world example, the render time is not trivial and can be avoided with ShouldRender, but doing so seems to keep subcomponents from re-rendering too.

Comment: See my added comments on why child components get rendered.  And does my solution override the default triggers.  No, returning `False` to `ShouldRender` stops  `StateHasChanged` placing the current RenderFragement onto the Renderer Queue. So the component doesn't render, and the Renderer isn't triggered to check for Parameter updates on Child Components.  My event just triggers the `StateHasChanged`.  It doesn't pass new Parameters into the component.  If the parameters are objects, no problem, but if they are primitives, the component will render using the old values.

Comment: On your last question - it's a matter of economics.  In Server mode, there's overhead with hundreds of users rendering at the same time.  In WASM, it's that one Browser thread, sitting twiddling it's thumbs waiting 99.99% of the time on the user.

Comment: In WebAssembly.  I find in a real-world site that certain user actions can hang the browser for 1-3 seconds, waiting for rerendering of hundreds/thousands of unchanged components.  When I implemented ShouldRender well, the UI became snappy again.  Another solution is to rely exclusively on primitive component parameters, but that's not always feasible (especially if we are more object-oriented and domain-driven in our architecture).  I'm working on a prototype NuGet package that might help and maybe your answer here will help it; I hope to try it soon.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - `ComponentBase` isn't exactly optimized for such a situation.  There's probably a lot of wasted renders being queued that don't need to happen  You should consider writing an optimized base component implementing `IComponent` directly.  You can implement your own `Equals` on your objects to detect real changes to control rendering.  Using `ShouldRender` is a bit of a blunt tool.